# Finding particular column value via regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file containing multiple rows as below.

```
56.0000         3       1
62.0000         3       1
74.0000         3       1
78.0000         3       1
82.0000         3       1
86.0000         3       1
90.0000         3       1
94.0000         3       1
98.0000         3       1
102.0000        3       1
106.0000        3       1
110.0000        3       0
116.0000        3       1
120.0000        3       1
```

Now I am looking for the row which has '0' in the third column .

I am using python regex package. What I have tried is `re.match("(.*)\s+(0-9)\s+(1)",line)` but of no help..

What should be the regular expression pattern I should be looking for?

Comment: Don't use a regex, read the file line by line, split each line and check the last column.

Comment: Third col ? Which thrid column? First line has 1 in third col. But 10 line, 2nd col seems to be blank

Comment: @DineshPundkar the one with 1 and 0..

Comment: What does the Objective C `NSRegularExpression` class have to do with Python?

Comment: Maybe `(?m)^\d+\.\d+\h+\d+\h+0$` That assumes the structure of this file is consistent...and that python supports the `\h`.

Comment: Instead of splitting, you can also do it with `str.endswith`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split line and read value from list.

```
>>> line = "56.0000         3       1"
>>> a=line.split()
>>> a
['56.0000', '3', '1']
>>> print a[2]
1
>>>
```

**Summary:**

```
f = open("sample.txt",'r')
for line in f:
    tmp_list = line.split()
    if int(tmp_list[2]) == 0:
        print "Line has 0"
        print line
f.close()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Line has 0
110.0000        3       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need a regex for this. You can *strip* trailing whitespaces from the right side of the line and then check the last character:

```
if line.rstrip()[-1] == "0": # since your last column only contains 0 or 1
   ...
```

Comment: Why not split the line? Then you can compare the third column (which is always present, just not 100% clear in the example) against 0.

Comment: If OP will only be using the lines containing `0` at the end, then splitting before checking might be unnecessary

Comment: What if the line has a `10` in the third column?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz: I was asking the same question but it seems that the third column contains only 0 or 1. *(at least in the example)*